# Hibernate: Re-attaching an object to a session causes uninitialized collections to be erased

Tags: hibernate

I am re-attaching a detached object with several persistent collections to a new Hibernate session with the following snippet:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().lock(myDetachedObject);
```

This code is executed in an AspectJ pointcut that is triggered whenever a persistent collection is accessed.

The object is not modified while it is detached, and once reattached, I am able to access and modify the object's persistent collections without issue. If I **do not access any of the persistent collections after reattaching**, however, then when I close my session and commit my work, **all of the persistent collections are deleted from the database**. It's as if I called the `clear()` method on each of them.

All my collections are explicitly configured as `CascadeType.ALL` and my understanding was that in doing so, they would be properly reattached to the session as part of a `LOCK` event. I understand that of I don't access any if the persistent collections, then the pointcut is triggered while Hibernate is preparing to flush the session. Is there some other way of reattaching an object to a session that prevents Hibernate from improperly deleting the collections?

**UPDATE**: I've tried other lock modes (`LockMode.READ`,`LockMode.UPGRADE`) and reattachment methods (calling `session.update()` instead of `session.lock()`). These predictably changed the behavior of the reattachment action, but not in the result. Collections are still deleted. I also wrote a small test to confirm that **the collections are deleted only if the object is reattached during the flush operation.**

Comment: have you tried to eagerly fetch the collections (`fetch = FetchType.EAGER`) of the reattached object. maybe you have some lazy-loading issue.

Comment: Eagerly fetching the collections would work, but it defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. I want the collections to be lazy loaded, and I am using session re-attachment to avoid the dreaded `LazyInitializationException`.